# What regular expression need for match nested expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm triying to make a regex in .net to match nested expresion.

I wan't to extract a **condition** and **value1** and **value2** like this:

> CASE WHEN **condition** THEN **value1** ELSE **value2** END

The string that i would like to match it's this:

```
CASE WHEN 5 + CASE WHEN 6 < 3 THEN 5 ELSE 2 END = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN 6 < 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END / (3 + CASE WHEN 5 < 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) END
```

Formatted string:

```
CASE WHEN 5 +
        CASE WHEN 6 < 3
        THEN 5
        ELSE 2
        END = 0
THEN 0
ELSE
    CASE WHEN 6 < 0
    THEN 2
    ELSE 1
    END / (3 + CASE WHEN 5 < 0
               THEN 2
               ELSE 0
               END)
END
```

I use a below Regex string, but only match without nested expresion:

```
(CASE WHEN )(?<cond>[\s\S]*?)( THEN )(?<val1>[\s\S]*?)( ELSE )(?<val2>[\s\S]*?)( END)
```

What regular expression need to extract the first "CASE WHEN" as below?

**Condition:** 5 + CASE WHEN 6 < 3 THEN 5 ELSE 2 END = 0

**Value1:** 0

**Value2:** CASE WHEN 6 < 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END / (3 + CASE WHEN 5 < 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: So you want CASE`WHEN 5` then `0` ELSE `all` END ? But you realize you're introducing parenthesis nesting as well ? I.e. `END / ()` which can be anywhere.

Comment: You can try something out knowing that Dot-Net uses `Balanced Group` counters to descent and rise like `(?<-Depth>)` and `(?<Depth>`) where the balance is checked at the end with a conditional `(?(Depth)(?!))`. In your case you would keep track of 2 separate counters. The regex can be done but given there is incomplete description regarding the parenthesis balance, seems unlikely at this point.

Comment: are you sure regex is what you ultimately need. This looks like a job for a parser like antlr or irony.net

Comment: No parenthesis are introducing. using Balanced Group like me but i don't expert in Regex, Can you help me on construct a regex with Depth?